# A fun series of riddles!

Tags: riddle, cipher

## All of the clues will lead up to the key for a Vigenere Cypher:

> eutnn wo vvsf.

## Clue 1 (from [www.riddles.com](http://www.riddles.com))

> I'm by nature solitary, scarred by spear and wounded by sword, weary of battle. I frequently see the face of war, and fight hateful enemies; yet I hold no hope of help being brought to me in the battle, before I'm eventually done to death. In the stronghold of the city sharp-edged swords, skilfully forged in the flame by smiths, bite deeply into me. I can but await a more fearsome encounter; it is not for me to discover in the city any of those doctors who heal grievous wounds with roots and herbs. The scars from sword wounds gape wider and wider; death blows are dealt to me by day and by night.

What am I?

## Clue 2 (from [www.riddles.com](http://www.riddles.com))

Use the answer from Clue 1 as the key to this Vigenere Cypher:

> lom ltjzlz m noatj, xsh zvbxpu a lvkljw, p key qga mwndhl uc nuqzbew fsnm.

What am I?

## Clue 3 (from [riddles.com](http://www.riddles.com))

Use the answer from Clue 2 as the key to this Vigenere Cypher:

> b hq sxooo hj vrl eep pdmzlk hm lruf. u jtwk bu xf fvq kkslgk eep tapesn ff pfdr mw ai itjij mfaygh kal afdzp.

What am I?

Use you answer for this as the key to the master cypher! Only the final answer is needed!

Comment: Do you have permission to use all of these? Right now, it seems like you've just copied riddles directly from another site and presented them as if they were a new puzzle.

Comment: Also, it seems that the answer to riddle 2 -- confirmed correct through an easy internet search -- does not decode riddle 3.

Comment: @Deusovi I don’t need permission to use other riddles. I have given credit to the original website, but have made an entirely new riddle out of them.

Comment: @InventPalooza if you write a book whose chapters are written by other people—even if you cite the original authors—can you claim that you wrote the book? In the same way, cobbling together a bunch of riddles you did not write does not make the final product "yours".

Comment: @Hugh That’s not the same thing, at all...

Comment: @InventPalooza I do not think so. The only thing that **you** have "added" to the riddle above is the encryption step. You cannot then turn around and claim that you've made "an *entirely* new riddle out of them". The way it's presented makes it seem otherwise.

Comment: @Deusovi what do you think of this?

Comment: Why did you use Vigenere? That's not hard to break... also I agree with Hugh and Deusovi.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, here I go. Invent Palooza has stated "Only the final answer is needed!", but I've written an explanation anyways.

> **MAGIC IS REAL.**
>
>  Since Clue #2 is relatively long, I opted to decode it through statistical analysis of the ciphertext. A few reasonable keys showed up, but **SHIELD** is most likely of them all. This can also be backed up by the fact that it is a reasonable solution to clue #1.
>
>  This means that clue #2 (decrypted) is "THE HIGHER I CLIMB THE HOTTER I ENGAGE I CANNOT ESCAPE MY CRYSTAL CAGE". Clearly the answer to this riddle is **THERMOMETER** (although "MERCURY" seems like a viable option, statistical analysis of the third clue showed that the key needed to be a little longer).
>
>  This means that clue #3 (decrypted) is "I AM BLACK OF EYE AND BRIGHT OF HAIR. I FAST IN TO THE GROUND AND FOLLOW MY LORD AS HE RACES AROUND THE WORLD." This time, Google was my friend; the answer is **SUNFLOWER**.
>
>  Using this to decode the original message, we get the final solution, **MAGIC IS REAL.**